# Flux (WebClient) Parallel Calls and then Post Processing on Collected List

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have a use case where I need to Run WebClient on Parallel Calls for 10 Upstream systems and timeout is 450ms, few of the Upstream System gives result in 80-150ms as p99 latency and few takes around ~300ms. **Here I need to collect data from each and then do the ranking**. I need a suggestion here If I use Collect() and then go for Ranking will that be blocking the thread by any chance as I need to get the data from all first and then go for Ranking. Can someone explain the **Thread flow** here? Thanks in advance!

**Example 1:**

```
Flux.just("red", "white", "blue")
        .log()
        .map(String::toUpperCase)
        .subscribe(System.out::println);

Output:

17:02:18.479 [main] INFO reactor.Flux.Array.1 - | onSubscribe([Synchronous Fuseable] FluxArray.ArraySubscription)
17:02:18.483 [main] INFO reactor.Flux.Array.1 - | request(unbounded)
17:02:18.483 [main] INFO reactor.Flux.Array.1 - | onNext(red)
RED
17:02:18.484 [main] INFO reactor.Flux.Array.1 - | onNext(white)
WHITE
17:02:18.484 [main] INFO reactor.Flux.Array.1 - | onNext(blue)
BLUE
17:02:18.485 [main] INFO reactor.Flux.Array.1 - | onComplete()
```

**Example 2:**

```
Flux.just("red", "white", "blue")
        .log()
        .map(String::toUpperCase)
        .collectList()
        .subscribe(System.out::println);

Output:

17:03:10.556 [main] DEBUG reactor.util.Loggers$LoggerFactory - Using Slf4j logging framework
17:03:10.622 [main] INFO reactor.Flux.Array.1 - | onSubscribe([Synchronous Fuseable] FluxArray.ArraySubscription)
17:03:10.625 [main] INFO reactor.Flux.Array.1 - | request(unbounded)
17:03:10.626 [main] INFO reactor.Flux.Array.1 - | onNext(red)
17:03:10.626 [main] INFO reactor.Flux.Array.1 - | onNext(white)
17:03:10.626 [main] INFO reactor.Flux.Array.1 - | onNext(blue)
17:03:10.627 [main] INFO reactor.Flux.Array.1 - | onComplete()
[RED, WHITE, BLUE]
```

In Example #2 I have added `.collectList()`

**Example #3**

```
    public Mono<List<String>> fetchUsers(List<String> userIds) {
        return Flux.fromIterable(userIds)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic())
            .flatMap(this::getUser)
            .collectList();
    }

    // This will be an HTTP Call p99 latency 450 ms
    public Mono<String> getUser(String id) {
        return webClient.get()
             .uri("/user/{id}", id)
             .retrieve()
             .bodyToMono(String.class);
    }
```

Comment: Some sample code would have been useful. Collect operators are non-blocking. Not sure what ranking means in your domain but if it's just a sort by on an in memory field, then that's also fine.

Comment: @MartinTarjányi Have added one sample code for reference, Here Ranking I mean the list has some attribute which I need to use for custom ranking. So for every onNext(), the thread is not blocked? and going back to the event loop and doing other tasks and when another event comes then again same thread will get notifies and process the next onNext() till onComplete()/onError()?

Comment: @MartinTarjányi Have added Example #3 with collect() and parallel call...here parallel call I mean Network I/O

Comment: Right, there is no blocking. Even the `subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic())` is unnecessary as no blocking I/O is involved here.

Comment: @MartinTarjányi Thanks Martin for the confirmation, ```getUser()``` code I just added for reference that will be a Network I/O which I am solving for. I have added comments just above the method also for reference.

Comment: Same applies there. Since you use Spring WebClient you don't need to worry about defining a scheduler as that client uses non-blocking IO.

Comment: You should remove `subscribeOn` as Martin mentioned, add `.log()` after `collectList` and look what happens. Your solution is correct, except `subscribeOn`

Comment: @AlexanderPankin
@MartinTarjányi
Thanks Guys, that worked ```.log()``` is a good practice to get a better clarity.. what's gng on